# When talking about periods of a function why is it common to introduce a factor of $2$?

Tags: soft-question, periodic-functions, convention

In many books I have read, when talking about periodic functions, they tend to write the period as $2\omega$. Why do we need the $2$? I haven't come across any working where the factor of $2$ is useful to have. Or is it just convention?

Comment: I have never seen anyone do this. What books are you reading?

Comment: An Introduction to the Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable by E.T Copson is one book I've seen it in. I was just wondering if there was any practical use...

Comment: If a function defined on an interval $(-\omega,\omega]$ is extended in a periodic fashion to the whole real line, then it will have period $2\omega$. Is this the kind of thing you're asking about?

Comment: Not necessarily, I have just seen a period defined with a factor of $2$. i.e. A function $f(z)$ is said to be periodic if there exists a non zero constant $2\omega$ such that $$f(z+2\omega)=f(z)$$ holds for all $z$.

Comment: Could you point to a page in Copson's book? The first time it's done in it, if possible.

Comment: Pg. 345 Chapter 13.

Comment: It seems to be an idiosyncrasy of the exposition for elliptic functions. I am not an expert on elliptic functions, but at first glance it seems to simplify some of the formulas, e.g. those in 13.32. Someone who is an expert should be able to give a better reason. You can edit your question to emphasize that you encountered this convention in a chapter about elliptic functions and to include the [tag:elliptic-functions] tag.